# Unexpected Call error of Jquery in IE 8

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

Problem on webpage:

http://choiceofficeinstallations.com/office/projects/

It works fine in all browsers including, chrome, safari, FF and Opera but not in IE 8....

IE 8 gives its famous Unexpected Call error on jquery.js file. I tried changing the position of the code, added noconflict, also tried TRY CATCH but nothing worked.

After hours, I am unable to understand why it is doing this.

Strange thing is that the same JQUERY is being used by a slider on site homepage and it works fine in IE 8 without errors. So I know that its not jquery.js, may be some other custom.js file that is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for that alert you setup in a loop :)

Comment: yes i was just trying to test myself as well ... will remove it now :)